# How to store float in a Byte array by shifting bits

Tags: java

I can store a int value in a byte array of size 4 using:

```
byte[] toByteArray(int value) {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte) (value >> 24),
            (byte) (value >> 16),
            (byte) (value >> 8),
            (byte) value};
    }
```

How can i store a float in a byte array using bit shift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use: [`Float.floatToIntBits(float val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29) to get the raw representation of the float and then convert the returned `int` to `byte[]`.

To read back the float, use [`Float.intBitsToFloat(int i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29)

Answer (score 4):

Remember that a [`float` is 4 bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). You can use a `ByteBuffer` to store the `float` and provide the byte array for you.

```
public byte[] toByteArray(float value) {    
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.putFloat(value);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

Internally this uses the `Bits` class which does something similar to what you were doing with your `toByteArray(int)` method.